# customizing the length of \dotfill

Tags: line, fill

How can I set a length of \dotfill ? 
I used \dotfill {3 cm} and \dotfill \phantom{3 cm} without success. I can create a box and put dotted line there, but can it not be simpler?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Write down your name ? \dotfill \newline 
What is your age ? \dotfill {3 cm} and Gender \dotfill {3cm} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the answers to your last question, which was almost identical, ["dotted line with appropriate length for answering a question?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332122/dotted-line-with-appropriate-length-for-answering-a-question/332124#332124)? The commands `\fillin` and `\answerline` in the answers provide exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Oh! Yes! That's sort of duplicate. Regrets! But have a look at my comment below ?

Comment: Just to understand the syntax, can you please explain \def\dotfill#1{\cleaders\hbox to #1{.}\hfill}

Comment: In your comments I can't find any argument why the answers there don't satisfy your needs. If you don't want to define a new command, then the answer is simple: No, there is no predefined command with an argument to fill the given width with dots. But it can be easily defined.

Comment: the correct answer to this question is @gernot's answer to the duplicate question that you asked before, why ask again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is `\dotline[<period>]{length}`.  EDITED to `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\dotfill#1{\cleaders\hbox to #1{.}\hfill}
\newcommand\dotline[2][.5em]{\leavevmode\hbox to #2{\dotfill{#1}\hfil}}
\begin{document}
\dotline{2.1cm}

xyz\dotline[2pt]{30pt}pdq
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's great. But is there no way other than to create a  new command ?

Comment: @Vaibhav To my knowledge, this is the LaTeX way to make periodic lines.  If you change the `{.}` to `{-}` in the definition, for example, you will have a dashed line.

Comment: the natural latex definition is as given in the duplicate question `\makebox[3cm]{\dotfill}` (or with a dotfill variant controlling the spacing) but if you use `\hbox` best to have a `\leavevmode` (see difference if you have `\dotline{2.1cm}\dotline{2.1cm}` at the start)