# Adding dots for signature in a document

Tags: signatures

Is there a smart way to add a number of dots in a place for a signature in 
a document?
For instance:

```
................
   Supervisor
```

It would be also perfect to control number of dots as a function of the length 
of what is under the dots.

Comment: Here is one of my answers, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332357/customizing-the-length-of-dotfill/332358#332358, which itself was already marked a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332357/customizing-the-length-of-dotfill/332358#332358

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

In order to control the dots width as a function of the text below it, use the `\widthof` command from `calc` package. It will exactly calculate the text width, so you may add a little space as `~` if you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\sigline}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{#1~}]{.\dotfill}\\#1}

\begin{document} 

\noindent%
\sigline{Supervisor}

\bigskip

\noindent%
\sigline{Another Long Name for Supervisor}

\end{document}
```

> [image]