# How can I make a form (like a contract or a request) in LaTeX and control the fields length?

Tags: lengths, forms

I had to do very quickly a form and all I found was the command `\hrulefill` & `\hruledots`
I did as in Form 1, but I wanted to make it as in Form 2, but to control the length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Form 1
\bigskip

Name: \hrulefill\\
Surname: \hrulefill\\

\bigskip

Form 2
\bigskip

Name \hrulefill Surname \hrulefill, student at University \hrulefill,
\\I am kindly asking to approve \hrulefill for the year \hrulefill.\\
I identify myself with passport no. \hrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image: form]

Comment: You can use `\rule{1cm}{.7pt}` for example.

Comment: `\makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}` could be another option.

Comment: See [dotted line with appropriate length for answering a question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332124/110998)